# Getting build error when converting xml (with tag) to tikxml in kotlin

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, tikxml

I want to convert a xml with tag values to tikxml. But failed.

XML that need to be converted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resCreateField>
  <countryCode mandatory="1">1</countryCode>
  <birthDate mandatory="1">1</birthDate>
  <policies>
     <skipEmailVerification>N</skipEmailVerification>
     <require2FactorConfiguration mandatory="1">Y</require2FactorConfiguration>
   </policies>
 </resCreateField>
```

My approaches:

```
 @Xml(name = "countryCode")
 data class CountryCode(
    @PropertyElement(name = "countryCode")
    val isCountryCodeMandatory: String? = null,

    @Attribute(name = "mandatory")
    val countryCodeMandatoryValue: String? = null
 )

 @Xml(name = "birthDate")
 data class BirthDate(
    @Attribute(name = "mandatory")
    val birthDateMandatoryValue: String? = null,

    @PropertyElement(name = "birthDate")
    val isBirthDateMandatory: String? = null
 )
 
 @Xml(name = "require2FactorConfiguration")
 data class Require2FactorConfiguration(
    @PropertyElement(name = "require2FactorConfiguration")
    val isEmailReceiveYNFlagMandatory: String? = null,

    @Attribute(name = "mandatory")
    val emailReceiveYNFlagMandatoryValue: String? = null
 )

 @Xml(name = "policies")
 data class Policies(

    @PropertyElement(name = "skipEmailVerification")
    val skipEmailVerification: String? = null,

    @Element(name = "require2FactorConfiguration")
    val require2FactorConfiguration: Require2FactorConfiguration
 )

 @Xml(name = "resCreateField")
 data class FieldInfoResponse(

    @Element(name = "countryCode")
    val countryCode: CountryCode?,

    @Element(name = "birthDate")
    val birthDate: BirthDate?,

    @Element(name = "policies")
    val policies: Policies?
 )
```

But i am getting the following error. I can not find out the reason.

```
error: The constructor parameter 'isBirthDateMandatory' in constructor 
BirthDate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in class com.example.utils.server.response.BirthDate  is annotated with a TikXml annotation. Therefore a getter method with minimum package visibility with the name getIsBirthDateMandatory() or isBirthDateMandatory() in case of a boolean must be provided. Unfortunately, there is no such getter method. Please provide one!
java.lang.String isBirthDateMandatory)
```

I used tikxml eralier for those xml which has no tag. But i can not solve for my case with tag.

I checked this link too https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml/blob/master/docs/AnnotatingModelClasses.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problems.

Here, value of countryCode 1 is a description.

```
<countryCode mandatory="1">1</countryCode>
```

So, xml should be written in this way

```
@Xml(name = "countryCode")
data class CountryCode(
   @TextContent
   val value: String? = null,

   @Attribute(name = "mandatory")
   val countryCodeMandatoryValue: String? = null
)
```